# USB mouse and / or keyboard stopped working after while or at boot time

Tags: usb, keyboard, bios, mouse

Recently I have a problem with USB keyboard and mouse or maybe the USB port itself.

Suddenly the keyboard and/or mouse stop working, then I need to unplug and plug
them to work… But not always… sometimes I must redo this few times.

I am using Linux Mint 17.1 on daily basis but this happens on Windows 7 and at boot time.

Note that the keyboard has LED illumination and this always works even when I can”t type anything. The mouse LED dies with the mouse.

Is it time for motherboard change?

Update (hardware):

```
Motherboard:  ASUS P8Z77 V PRO (LGA1155)
Keyboard:     CM Storm Ultimate Quickfire
Mouse:        Roccat Kone XTD+
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's sometimes happening *before* boot, and with two different operating systems, it's very likely a hardware problem. It could be a bad cable, bad USB jack/plug, and/or a problem with the motherboard USB hardware.

Your PC likely has more than one USB port? Are all the ports having the same issue?

If it only happens on a certain port, or group of ports, you can just stop using that port or group of ports. If you need more ports, get an inexpensive hub.

If it's happening on all your USB ports, it could be either your motherboard (as multiple ports likely share the same USB controller/hub chip) or your keyboard and/or mouse. I've had cables become intermittent (especially on mice). The wires eventually break inside the cable and you have intermittent problems. The solution is to try a different keyboard and/or mouse.

If all the ports behave the same, replacing the keyboard/mouse doesn't help, and it's a PC with an open PCI slot, you can get an inexpensive USB board to add reliable USB ports. Or you can replace the motherboard and/or PC.

Comment: I already tested the back USB ports (and this happens there for sure)... I will check the front ones and post a comment with the results. The problem may be time - as this happens not very often...